# MySQL / Fusion IO Configuration Question

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, mysql-5.5, fusion-io

I need a little configuration optimization. I think what I have is pretty good but feel like there's still room for improvement.

**Current Config**

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

#innodb
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 32M

innodb_read_io_threads=8
innodb_write_io_threads=8

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_io_capacity=10000
#eliminating double buffering
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
flush_time=86400

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0
#tmpdir=/dev/shm
#tmpdir=/usr/tmpfs
skip-name-resolve
#skip-locking
#safe-show-database
query_cache_limit=4M
query_cache_size=256M
sort_buffer_size=8M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
max_connections=5000
interactive_timeout=60
wait_timeout=300
connect_timeout=30
thread_cache_size=32
key_buffer=124M
tmp_table_size=4096M
max_heap_table_size=256M
join_buffer=16M
max_connect_errors=2000
table_cache=2048
thread_concurrency=12
long_query_time=5
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-slow.log
#table_definition_cache=384
max_allowed_packet=1024M
#server-id=20
#log-bin=mysql-bin
#expire_logs_days=10

event_scheduler=ON

#master-host =
#master-user =
#master-password =
#master-port = 3306

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

**Dedicated Database server specs**

- VMWare VM
- Dual Quad Xeon X5680  @ 3.33GHz (8 vCPU)
- 24gb RAM
- Fusion IO mounted on /var/lib/mysql
- Rough total of 500 tables between all databases

I know this kind of question really kind of requires eyes on the database server but I will gladly append information to this question as needed in order to get a much better configuration.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the question I answered two months ago : [MySQL using too much CPU](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44896/mysql-using-too-much-cpu/44906#44906)

FusionIO tends to be CPU aggressive. You will have to fight back by

- Tuning InnoDB

  - more read threads ([innodb_read_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads)), perhaps 16
  - more write threads ([innodb_write_io_threads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads)), perhaps 16
  - raising or lowering [innodb_io_capacity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_io_capacity) to match IOPs of your FusionIO device
  - raise the Log Buffer ([innodb_log_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size)) to 1G
  - raise the Log File ([innodb_log_file_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size)) to 128M
- Converting as much of your MyISAM to InnoDB as possible because changes to `.MYD` are cached in the OS memory rather than any MySQL buffers

I would also lower [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) to 2000 unless you know for a certainty to will get over 4500 simultaneous DB Connections. If you really need 5000, upgrade the VM's RAM to 48GB.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks Rolando. I do remember that thread and things have gotten way better with those config changes from then. I do know for a fact that I hit about 2500 simultaneous connections during peak periods which is why I set it to 5000 to give me some growing room. I'll tune a little more with the info you gave me here and in the last thread.

Comment: Wow, you are the same person from the first question. If these answers really helped, please mark them accepted by clicking the check mark.