# What are the right ways to analyse and tune up innodb_thread_concurrency in mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, mysql-5.7

I'm in a plan to increase thread concurrency in my production MySQL server 5.7 but not sure, before what are the params/configurations that need to be measured and configured to increase the thread concurrency to the right optimal value. When checked with the MySQL official documentation, there seems to be a note stating

```
The correct values of these variables depend on your environment and workload.Try a range of different values to determine what value works for your applications. Before limiting the number of concurrently executing threads, review configuration options that may improve the performance of InnoDB on multi-core and multi-processor computers
```

When referred with other blogs, came up with some formulas as

```
concurrency = 2 x no.of cpu
```

And in some other similar blogs, there they stated along with disk as

```
concurrency = 2 * (NumCPUs + NumDisks)
```

How to benchmark my MySQL workload to tune up with the thread concurrency?

Currently, I'm having

```
thread concurrency = 8  
RAM = 64 GB
CPU = 20 core
```

Occasionally, There seems to be sudden increase in overall thread usage by slow queries and all 8 threads were under operation resulting in making normal running queries to get slowed down :(

Hence what's the right way to tune up with thread concurrency ?

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Will check and update with you

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of keeping this topic up-to-date, infinite concurrency is no longer advised for MySQL 5.7 and above. Why ???

In my early years in the DBA StackExchange, I used to recommend setting [innodb_thread_concurrency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) to `0` based on what I learned firsthand at Percona Live 2011 (See my `Jun 20, 2012` post [MySQL transaction size - how big is too big?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19569/mysql-transaction-size-how-big-is-too-big/19580#19580)).

Five years later, I learned that Percona had benchmarked different values for [innodb_thread_concurrency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_thread_concurrency) and found out that CPU performance tops out at `64` for Oracle's MySQL:

- `Aug 14, 2017` : [MariaDB 10.1.22 to use more RAM rather than CPU](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183403/mariadb-10-1-22-to-use-more-ram-rather-than-cpu/183425#183425) (My DBA SE Post)
- `Mar 17, 2016` : [Percona Server 5.7 performance improvements](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/17/percona-server-5-7-performance-improvements/) (Percona Blog I read)

Therefore, it must be said

- `0` is the best value before MySQL 5.7
- `64` is the best value for MySQL 5.7 and beyond

Comment: Do you not NEED to know how many CORES on the the equipment before using 64?  Some people suggest max of CORES * .8  rounded down to allow other application functions some access to cores.  In any case many people are running with no where near 64 cores available.

Comment: @WilsonHauck In the past, 0 lets InnoDB decide what's best before Oracle MySQL 5.7 and with earlier versions of MariaDB. 64 is the best value now. Leaving it 0 is best for Percona Server and newer versions of Oracle MySQL and MariaDB. Please keep in mind that this is about threads not cores. One can still use that formula but may be unwittingly throttling the application. You could gradually lift it beyond 8  and see top and innotop.

Comment: Rolando, Throttling helps avoid the 'stampeding herd' of processes trying to be completed and no process getting finished. Thank you for your very helpful details.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to `0` and let InnoDB pick the concurrency.

20 cores with currency=8 means that at least 12 cores will always be idle.

What is the value of `Max_used_connections`?  If that is not very high, the "concurrency" is not your main problem.

Meanwhile, let's see one of the 'slow' queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be ways to speed it up, possibly decreasing the I/O.

For more analysis of your VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS, let's see them.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning

Comment: Thanks.. Will look into it