# How can I optimize this mySQL table that will need to hold 5+ million rows?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

The table has about 12 rows.

**Indexes:**

`id`int(11), Unique, auto-increment, primary

`ATTACHMENTID`varchar(14), Unique

`MLSNUMBER`bigint(20)

`POSITION`int(10)

`FILETYPE`varchar(32)

I'm doing an extended insert with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause.
Each insert has anywhere from 300-10,000 records.
The more records in the table, the longer the query takes.

With 0 rows, the query took about 5-10 seconds.
After about 300,000 rows, the query was taking 50 seconds.

What would be the best way to optimize this table? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the table MyISAM or innodb?

Comment: It is InnoDB.  _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the table is InnoDB

- Bulk Insert Buffer (bulk_insert_buffer_size) is no good for you because it handles bulk inserts for MyISAM tables only
- `DISABLE KEYS` / `ENABLE KEYS` only works for MyISAM. InnoDB handles secondary index processing in the system tablespace ibdata1.

  - [**InnoDB will throw a warning about this**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10407/877)
  - See my post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9525780/491757
  - See the bug report : http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5187

You may have to resort to altering the InnoDB buffer protocol to handle only INSERTs : 
[Mysql load from infile stuck waiting on hard drive](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20862/mysql-load-from-infile-stuck-waiting-on-hard-drive/20864#20864)

Unless you plan to have store values in `MLSNUMBER` bigger than 2147483647, you may want to consider making `MLSNUMBER` an `INT` (4 bytes) instead of `BIGINT` (8 bytes) to save space on secondary index creation. If your values for `MLSNUMBER` are less than 4294967296, maybe `MLSNUMBER` should be `INT UNSIGNED`.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it takes progressively longer when your table has a lot of rows is due to having to write the indexes. Try turning offing indexes for the table before inserting, then re-enable afterwards:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DISABLE KEYS;

-- Your insert statement

ALTER TABLE my_table ENABLE KEYS;
```

Disabling keys only affects the updating of non-unique keys, so `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` will still work as intended:

> ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS tells MySQL to stop updating **nonunique indexes**. ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS then should be used to re-create missing indexes. [[src]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Won't this make ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not work?

Comment: Clarified that point...it should still work.