# bulk_insert_buffer_size and InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I read the following on this page

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

> bulk_insert_buffer_size MyISAM uses a special tree-like cache to make
>   bulk inserts faster for INSERT ... SELECT, INSERT ... VALUES (...),
>   (...), ..., and LOAD DATA INFILE. This variable limits the size of the
>   cache tree in bytes per thread. Setting it to 0 disables this
>   optimization. Note: This cache is used only when adding data to a
>   non-empty table. The default value is 8MB. This variable was added in
>   MySQL 4.0.3. This variable previously was named
>   myisam_bulk_insert_tree_size.

I take this to mean that bulk_insert_buffer_size has no bearing on
InnoDB tables, only on MyISAM tables. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you are correct. I wrote about this before: [How can I optimize this mySQL table that will need to hold 5+ million rows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21583/how-can-i-optimize-this-mysql-table-that-will-need-to-hold-5-million-rows/21594#21594)

WHen it comes to bulk loading InnoDB tables, one of the most frequently ignored settings to disable is [**innodb_doublewrite**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite).

## InnoDB Architecture

[image: InnoDB Architecture]

Please note the double write buffer inside the system tablespace file `ibdata1`. Every time a 16K page is written to an InnoDB table or transaction log, the page is written to the double wrote buffer first. All you need to do is disable it, load your data, and reenable it.

## STEP 01 : Disable Fast Shutdown

```
mysql -uroot -p... -ANe"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0"
```

## STEP 02 : Restart mysql without the double write buffer

```
service mysql restart --innodb-doublewrite=0
```

## STEP 03 : Load the InnoDB data

## STEP 04 : Restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

## CAVEAT

You can disable the foreign key checks and the unique checks as well. Any standard mysqldump will do that for you already.

Comment: unless it is (properly configured) zfs, disabling doublewrite may cause page corruptions (when partial write happens).

Comment: do not do this, this has been proven to corrupt data! 
 https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/23/improve-innodb-performance-write-bound-loads/

Comment: Hey @MuhammadOmerAslam .I have been recommending this for many years (https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a877%20innodb%20doublewrite). I still do this. In fact, I did this for a personal client just 2 months ago. He was reloading a DB Server for Production but was not live. It dramatically cut the reload time by well over 50%. Other than reloading huge amounts of data, you are so right and so is that post you mentioned. I have read that post back then. Yet, I still disable `innodb_doublewrite` when other means of reloading fast do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it only works with MyISAM tables.

## For Innodb we need to diable unique_checks and foreign_key_checks using

set unique_checks=0; set foreign_key_checks=0; diable auto_commit.

inserts......

## set unique_checks=1; set foreign_key_checks=1; enable auto_commit.

Which improves bulk inserts performance.